# validar trigger que antes de realizar un delete valide que si falta 30 minutos para llegar a la hora registrada en la tabla no realize en delete?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, trigger, delete

Tengo una tabla llamada CITAS en esta tabla le prestaremos atención a dos columnas que son citFechaInicio y citHoraInicio, la primera columna se registra la fecha de la cita y la segunda columna se registra la hora de inicio de una cita, lo que quiero es que mi trigger antes de realizar un delete mire si la fecha de inicio es igual a la actual y si falta 30 minutos o menos para la hora de inicio el delete no se realize, un ejemplo

```
citFechaInicio    citHoraInicio
 2020-22-09         11:00 AM
```

Actualmente estamos a esta fecha y son las 10:30AM y faltan 30 minutos para las 11:00AM en este caso quiero que el delete no se ejecute, pero si son las 09:00AM a esta hora es posible por que el rango de las 9 hasta las 11 supera los 30 minutos

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A continuación te proporciono un código para que adaptes en tu Trigger:

```
SET @AHORA= NOW(); -- MOMENTO ACTUAL
-- A CONTINUACIÓN USO -30 PARA SIMULAR TU FECHA YA "NO CANCELAR" SI LE PONES -29 "SI CANCELAR"
SET @CITAINICIO=DATE_ADD(@AHORA, INTERVAL -29 MINUTE); -- MOMENTO ACTUAL MENOS 30 MINUTOS; AUMENTA O DISMINUYE PARA OBSERVAR COMPÒRTAMIENTO
SET @MINUTOS = -30; -- NEGATIVO PARA QUTAR POSITIVO PARA AGREGAR

SELECT @AHORA, DATE_ADD(@AHORA, INTERVAL @MINUTOS MINUTE), @CITAINICIO, 
    CASE WHEN @CITAINICIO>DATE_ADD(@AHORA, INTERVAL @MINUTOS MINUTE) THEN 'NO CANCELAR' ELSE 'SI CANCELAR' END
```

La variable `@CITAINICIO` es la que mencionas como (en conjunto) `citFechaInicio` con `citHoraInicio`; ya con ello puedes comparar restando los `@MINUTOS` que desees proporcionar antes de su cancelación.

**ACTUALIZACION**

Te ilustro como sería el restarle los **N** minutos y su comparación con el dato respectivo al momento actual `NOW()`.
En tu caso seria por ejemplo dentro del **Store Procedure** o **Trigger**... ponerlo en condicional para que haga lo que corresponda a tu **Regla de Negocio**:

```
IF (@CITAINICIO>DATE_ADD(@AHORA, INTERVAL @MINUTOS MINUTE)) THEN
// Aqui entra si son 30 o menos minutos antes de la cita
ELSE
// Aqui si hay mas de 30 minutos antes de la cita
END IF;
```

Al inicio para efectos del ejemplo `@CITAINICIO` corresponde a tu **Fecha y Hora de inicio**; este es un tipo de datos que contiene ambos (no es un varchar, string, o similar); tal que, si los tienes por separado o como texto deberás convertirlos a **fecha con hora** para realizar la comparación.

Respecto a *"tengo que recibir el id de la cita para recibir los valores de la citFechaInicio y citHoraInicio"*; no esta muy claro; tu planteamiento inicial *"Tengo una tabla llamada CITAS en esta tabla le prestaremos atención a dos columnas que son citFechaInicio y citHoraInicio [...]  lo que quiero es que mi trigger antes de realizar un delete[...]"* la tabla ya tiene los datos ¿por que indicas que tienes que recibir ambos?; será que recibes el `id` y con el buscar el elemento/fila que le corresponde para eliminarlo.

Ya sea en **SP**, **Trigger**, etc si recibes el `id` solo basta obtengas la Fecha con hora de la cita y la compares como antes ya puse de ejemplo.

Ahora que si tu duda es como hacer el [**SP**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) o [**Tirgger**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) son otro temas a tu planteamiento. En el caso del **Trigger** tendrias que [*lanzar* un error para que no continue](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-signal-resignal/)

Comment: Voy a lo probar y te estaré contando, pero ahora que me pongo a pensar esto funcionaria en un procedimiento almacenado ya que tengo que recibir el id de la cita para recibir los valores de la citFechaInicio y citHoraInicio

Comment: Una preguntar a donde van los valores registrados de la hora de incio y fecha de incio de una cita

Comment: es necesario unirlo las dos columnas con tipo de dato datetime, no hay una manera de forma separada como los tengo fecha de inicio DATE hora de inicio TIME